# Monitoring Celery, what should I use?

Tags: python, django, monitoring, celery

I'm using Django, Celery, and Django-Celery. I'd like to monitor the state/results of my tasks, but I'm a little confused on how to do that.

Do I use `./manage.py celeryev`, `./manage.py celerymon`, `./manage.py celerycam`? Do I run `sudo /etc/init.d/celeryevcam start`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Run:

```
./manage.py celeryd -E
./manage.py celerycam
```

The first starts a worker with events enabled.

Now you can find task results in the django admin interface. Ensure you have djcelery in your INSTALLED_APPS. If you want to see task state use also celerymon.

Comment: Thanks!

So, what does the celeryevcam init script do? I looked at its source and it looks like it runs celeryev, which I thought was an curses event viewer, which wouldn't make sense to run as a daemon with no one to look at it, right?

Comment: Wait, I think I've got it. celeryev is normally used for celery on its own and doubles as a viewer and camera, but django-celery provides celerycam which just does the camera part, and the init script is called celeryevcam because you can use it with either celeryev or celerycam. Is that right?

Comment: i never heard celeryevcam, sorry

Comment: It's one of the daemon scripts: https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/contrib/debian/init.d/celeryevcam

Comment: The link has changed to https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/contrib/generic-init.d/celeryevcam, this can be used to take the snapshots.

Comment: As of version 3.1, `celeryd` has been superseded by `celery worker`, so the first command should be `./manage.py worker -E`. Here is a comparison of [old and new celery commands](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html#old-command-line-programs-removed-and-deprecated).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question. But for those visiting in the future, [Celery Flower](http://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a great tool. It is also [recommended](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#flower-real-time-celery-web-monitor) by Celery. Here are some cool features from the link above:

### Real-time monitoring using Celery Events

- Task progress and history
- Ability to show task details (arguments, start time, runtime, and more)
- Graphs and statistics

### Remote Control

- View worker status and statistics
- Shutdown and restart worker instances
- Control worker pool size and autoscale settings
- View and modify the queues a worker instance consumes from
- View currently running tasks
- View scheduled tasks (ETA/countdown)
- View reserved and revoked tasks
- Apply time and rate limits
- Configuration viewer
- Revoke or terminate tasks

### Broker monitoring

- View statistics for all Celery queues
- Queue length graphs

### HTTP API

### Basic Auth, GitHub OAuth2 and Google OpenID authentication