# How to properly configure djcelery results backend to database

Tags: django, celery, djcelery

I'm trying to setup djangocelery to store task results in the databse.

I set:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'
```

then I synced and migrated the db (no errors).

Celery is working and tasks get processed (I can get the results), but admin shows there is no tasks. In the database are two tables `celery_taskmeta` and `djcelery_taskmeta`. First one is holding the results and second one is displayed in admin. Anyone has insight how to configure it properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitoring Celery, what should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809408/monitoring-celery-what-should-i-use)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check [the doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-result-backend), when you use djcelery, set `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="database"` or don't even bother to write this line because djcelery sets it by default.

The result is stored in `celery_taskmeta` table, you should register `djcelery.models.TaskMeta` to admin by yourself:

```
# in some admin.py, which is contained by an app after `djcelery` in `INSTALLED_APPS`
# or directly in djcelery/admin.py

from djcelery.models import TaskMeta
class TaskMetaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('result',)    
admin.site.register(TaskMeta, TaskMetaAdmin)
```

Comment: I changed `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` to `"database"` but still id doesn't work.I have TaskState table in admin in application djcelery, and other models from that app registered in the admin are working --- worker model shows connected workers.

Comment: TaskState is for monitoring: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#django-admin-monitor

Comment: Also note that monitoring does not work for all brokers. Only those that have 'fanout' support in this table does: http://kombu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#transport-comparison

Answer (score 10):

Related question with right answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809408/monitoring-celery-what-should-i-use).

You should actually run

```
python manage.py celery worker -E
```

and

```
python manage.py celerycam
```

After that tasks results will be displayed in admin (Djcelery › Tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Moving the config update e.g.
app.conf.update(CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database.DatabaseBackend')

to the end of file celery.py did the trick for me .